# i have to print a table with the details if any student has <20 in any subject the status should be failed and colored red

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

i've tried this for to print the status of a student as "fail" if he scores less than 20 in any subject and "topper" if the sum of subjects total highest among all and if he fails the total "tr" color has to be red font

```js
 public studentData = [
     {
         "name":"rajiv",
         "marks":{
             "Maths":18,
             "English":21,
             "Science":45
         },
         "rollNumber":"KV2017-5A2"
     },
     {
         "name":"abhishek",
         "marks":{
             "Maths":43,
             "English":30,
             "Science":37
         },
         "rollNumber":"KV2017-5A1"
     },
     {
         "name":"zoya",
         "marks":{
             "Maths":42,
             "English":31,
             "Science":50
         },
         "rollNumber":"KV2017-5A3"
     }
 ]

    totalScore(){
    this.studentData.forEach(a => {
    let res = a.marks.English + a.marks.Maths + a.marks.Science
    this.total.push(res)
    console.log(this.total)
    }
    )
    }
```

**output : [84, 110, 123]**

```
status(){
this.studentData.forEach(a => {
let sample = a.marks
let values = [];

for (var key in sample) {
values.push( sample[key]);
};
console.log(values);
let val = values.find(b => b<20)
 console.log(val)
 return 'fail' }) }
```

**output:[18, 21, 45]  [43, 30, 37] [42, 31, 50]**

how can i print the status accordingly please help me out

Comment: what did you try in your template?

Comment: <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Student Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Roll Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Marks</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let data of studentData">            
            <td>{{data.name | titlecase }}</td>
            <td>{{data.rollNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{data.marks.Maths+data.marks.English+data.marks.Science}}</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

Answer (score 0):

i made a stackblitz with a workaround.

This can be upgraded but it's rudimentary

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zazjv

Basically i managed the status with [ngClass] and printed in view the table you want.

added .red class in component.css

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I modified a little my stackblitz. This might work for you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ngClass` directive for dynamically assigning the classes to the template.
[NgClass-Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

If it's just single style property change use `ngStyle` directive instead.
[NgStyle-Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

In your case, the total function can be modified as

```
  studentData = [];
  total = [];
  studentStatus = [];
    totalScore() {
        this.total = this.studentData.map(
          student =>
            student.marks.English + student.marks.Maths + student.marks.Science
        );
      }
```

this will print the status of each student.

```
      status() {
        this.studentStatus = this.studentData.map(student =>
          student.marks.find(mark => mark < 20) ? "Failed" : "Passed"
        );
      }
```

If you want to map status and marks together do it as below

```
 this.studentStatus = this.studentData.map(student => ({
  ...student,
  status: student.marks.find(mark => mark < 20) ? "Failed" : "Passed"
}));
```

`studentStatus` will have all the student details object along with other property `status`

use `*ngFor` to loop through and write conditional styles using `ngClass` or `ngStyle`